# Jquery select() and IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote small function. When i type something in input (text input) and then click on this input, all text highlights, so user can delete long text, without typing backspace many times.

```
$('.search').mouseup(function(){
    var save_this = $(this);
    save_this.select();
    save_this.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
});
```

This works well for android and desktop, but not for IOS. Any ideas ?

[Here](http://www.skyscanner.com/) i see, that on IOS while on click from, or to, text is selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269722/selecting-text-on-focus-using-jquery-not-working-in-safari-and-chrome

Answer (score 2):

I think you should listen to `touchend` event on mobile devices instead of `mouseup`.

Comment: Sorry, this don't work (as i said - android works well, just not IOS)