# Safari: focus event doesn't work on button element

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

The focus event works fine on all browsers but Safari when it has been clicked.

And it works fine on div[tabindex] element, but don't work on button or input:button element.

It also can get the focus event when I use $('.btn').focus().

Why does the focus event haven't triggered on click ?

Here is my code:

```js
$(".btn").focus(function (e) {
 $(".result").append("<p>Event:"+e.type+", target:"+e.target+"</p>");
})
```

```css
.result{min-height:200px;border:1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">button 1</button>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="button 2"/>
<div class="btn" tabindex="0">div element</div>
<h1>
Result:
</h1>
<div class="result">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269767/2731261

```
$(".btn").mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I think that sames like not the same issue. 
It only reproduce on Safari. What I want is get the focus event on the button when clicked.

Comment: Well I just found this documentation basically saying Safari does not focus the button after click: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

Answer (score 18):

Documentation tells is not supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

[image]

Comment: Old but gold. Thanks.
For my particular case, I just changed my button element  to div *and* set its [tabindex attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) accordingly (tabindex="1" for me).

Answer (score 8):

> Why does the focus event haven't triggered on click ?

We found through research that Safari and FireFox on Macs do not set focus on buttons when you click on them.

The way we fixed that was to add a click listener to our buttons and call focus() on the button that was clicked.

In Angular it looked like this:

```
<button (click)="myClickFunction(); $event.target.focus();>My Button</button>
```

Comment: Fire Fox seems to focus just fine now (July 2023).

Answer (score 4):

See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13724

This is working as intended on MacOS.  Clicking a button, radio button, or checkbox doesn't give the element focus- thus it can't lose focus and trigger a blur.

The solution is to give it a click event that gives the element focus.

Comment: Giving element click event via addEventListener doesn't give it the ability to receive focus on click. You have to call focus method on the element when it is clicked `button.addEventListener('click', e => e.currentTarget.focus())`

Answer (score 3):

Use the code below to fix all the buttons on a web page:

```
(function() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  for (var i=0; i<=buttons.length-1; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      var button = buttons[index];
      button.addEventListener("click", function() { button.focus(); });
    })(i);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. The only caveat is that it will need some tweaking if you're planning to use it in an ajax environment, to avoid saddling buttons with event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 8+ solution:

1. in your button tag
   add #toggleButton and (click)="onClick(); $event.stopPropagation()"

exp:

```
<button #toggleButton type="button"
    (click)="onClick(); $event.stopPropagation()"></button>
```

2. in your component.ts add
   ==>before constructor

*** `@ViewChild('toggleButton', { static: true }) toggleButton: ElementRef;`

---

```
onclick(){
        this.toggleButton.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some Safari settings that are not enabled by default:
•   Go to Safari > Preferences.

- Click on the Advanced tab.
- Check the box at the bottom that says "Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage."