# How to auto-highlight text input after setting .val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I'm trying to dynamically set some text in an input field, and then display it, and finally auto-highlight/auto-select it.

If I don't use .val() and instead use value="something" hardcoded on the input it works perfectly.

If I add .val() to the method chain, it just puts the cursor in the box but doesn't highlight the text.

Any idea how I might do this?

In the example below, `$(this)` refers to the link they click on "Rename" which causes inline edit box to appear. The `.next()` refers to the input.

```
$(this).hide().next().val(oldName).show().focus();
```

Comment: Undefined method auto-highlight in question given.

Comment: When the input is focused, I want it to be as if they hit command+A or control+A

Comment: I would say please give some fiddle to help you even better.

Comment: have a look at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).hide().next().val(oldName).show().focus().select();
```

if that's the moment you want it to happen. It will apply to the `.next()` element, not `$(this)` but since you've hidden `$(this)` it's probably what you're after.

Comment: .select() worked, thanks :) I cant mark this as the answer yet, but I will