# Jquery .select() doesnt work property on focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Id like to select all text from input on focusing:

```
<input id="selectMe" value="123" />
<input type="button" id="focusHim" value="Im working fine" />
```

JS:

```
$('#selectMe').focus( function() {
    $(this).select();
    console.log('focus fired');
});

// little test if focus event works fine
$('#focusHim').click( function() {
    $('#selectMe').focus();
});
```

This simplified code works fine, but sometimes there are some issues.

Here you have fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daxv2/

To see my problem, please click on input `#selectMe`, then click somewhere else and on `#selectMe` again. You will see, text is selected every even attempt. I don't know why.

P.S.
When you change `focus` to `click` it works perfect:

```
$('#selectMe').click( function() {
        $(this).select();
        console.log('focus fired');
    });
```

So i suppose there is some problem with `focus` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the WebKit browsers interfere with this because of the mouseup event.

I added this and it seems to work fine:

```
$('#selectMe').mouseup(function () {
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daxv2/6/

Comment: [Plagiarism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery)!

Comment: @billyonecan so you're saying because someone else wrote it, it means that i can't come to the same conclusion?

Comment: No, it was more because it's identical word for word

Comment: @billyonecan umm.. i checked and its not. get your facts straight bub.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `click` event instead of `focus`. It works fine, also you can simplify your code by  using `this.select()` instead of  `$(this).select()`
http://jsfiddle.net/daxv2/8/

Comment: I know about `click` event, but thanks for `this.select()`!