# highlight and select a text of a input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I cannot find a solution in stackoverflow. I have an input filed and a value. I want the value to be selected and highlighted, so the user can easily copy the text. How can I do it with jQuery?

```
<input value="copy this text easily"  />
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Create an `<input>` element and give it a `value`?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can use the [`select`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) function:

```
$("input").select();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('input').focus()
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xsAhu/)**

You may need to change the selector though. I wrote a generic selector since there in only 1 input in the example.

Comment: it is not highlighted in firefox :(