# ASP NET TextBox on focus event not firing. I want the text in the textbox to be selected on single click on the text box

Tags: jquery, textbox, focus

```
jquery code:
$("#<%=tbExcludeFilter.ClientID%>").focus(function () {
    $("#<%=tbExcludeFilter.ClientID%>").select();
})

asp:
<asp:TextBox ID="tbExcludeFilter" runat="server" CssClass="autosuggestIncluded" PlaceHolder="Search by employee nameor id"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want the text in the textbox to be selected on single click on the textbox instead of double click.

Comment: Does this work in classic html?

Comment: I am able to do it using the browser console.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of it? Where is the script in your page?

Comment: I am not able to create the jsfiddle as I am using ASP.NET web forms and generating at server side.

Comment: You could create one of the outcome HTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v5pB9/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the javascript wrapped in a $(document).ready? I would think it would look like this rendered for it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tbExcludeFilter").focus(function() {
    $(this).select();
  });
});
```

This thread has details, too: [Select all contents of textbox when it receives focus (JavaScript or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: I tried keeping it inside $(document). But still couldn't y the focus event is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Solution That worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#<%=tbExcludeFilter.ClientID%>").focus(function () {
        setTimeout(HighLight(this),10);
        });
        });
            javascript:
            var HighLightText(element){
        setTimeout(element.select(),0); // time out for Chrome and Safari
        }
```

Thanks