# "Select All" on clicking Bootstrap input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say i have this input:

```
  <li><input type="text" id="elementHeight" class="form-control" placeholder="Height"> </li>
```

and i want to ''Select All'' in the input field when the user clicks on it.

Comment: What do you mean by `Select All`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input').click(function () {
    this.select();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It does select it but then unselects it.

Answer (score 11):

From a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery), I got an answer I prefer.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" />
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/480756/989227

Answer (score 2):

when the field is focused ,clicked

```
$("#elementHeight").focus(function(){
    this.select();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Bootstrap 5, there's `user-select-all`, but it wasn't working for inputs so I added this to my script and it works like a charm:

```js
$(".user-select-all").focus(function () {
   $(this).select();
});
```

[Bootstrap 5 doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/interactions/#text-selection)

Comment: Huh, in considering all the possibly useful cases for `user-select-all`, why would bootstrap exclude form `<input>`s?