# Select and focus text in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which gets edited on click and edited data is saved back.

Now i was to able get **it focused**, but somehow not able to **select all text** and also get the **focus at end of text instead at start**.

```
<div class="edit-section"> 
    <a>Name</a>
</div>

 <a href='#' class="edit">Edit</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('.edit').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.edit-section').focus();
        $(this).siblings('.edit-section').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        $(this).siblings('.edit-section').attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');

    });
```

I tried following but does not seem to work.

```
 $(this).siblings('.edit-section').focus(function () { $(this).select() });
```

**Edit: New to jQuery**

Comment: Have you wrapped your jQuery script with $(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ }); ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480735/select-all-contents-of-textbox-when-it-receives-focus-javascript-or-jquery and make sure to read the comments.

Comment: Why use div along with ``contenteditable`` attribute? Cant the same can be achieved using ``<input type="text">``?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Yes i have

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/276Xn/**

Comment: @adeneo This works and text is selected,but for some reason the edited data is not saved when i do this :(

Comment: How do you focus "at the end of the text" and at the same time select all?

Comment: @David Select all is not done np,but it should atleast be focused at end of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you can call `.select()` on contenteditables, but try using `execCommand` instead when the element is focused:

```
document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F65D3/

Comment: Mind if you explain a little why it works? This is new to me and I wanna learn about it.

Comment: This works and text is selected,but for some reason the edited data is not saved when i do this :(

Comment: This code has nothing to do with data transfers, it just selects the text. Maybe you need to create another question for that problem.

Comment: OK thanks.But how do i set focus at end of text instead of start

Comment: @Richa Avoid asking follow-ups in the comments. It’s better if you just create a new question instead.